# package maintainers guide?

Tags: package-management, documentation, backport

I am trying to learn more about packaging, package maintenance, back-porting, and creating compliant deb packages. I have been reading this:
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

but I am starting to have concerns about its relevance to Ubuntu specific package creation. As in, many of the references are Debian specific. And, while I could create a bunch of Debian environmental variables, and cautiously proceed, am wondering if there is a similar document, somewhere, outlining how to be a package maintainer in Ubuntu.

does such a document, or tutorial exist for Ubuntu package management?
should I stop worrying, and just keep trying with this tutorial?

Comment: That's the correct guide. The behaviours of tools change slightly to adapt to the differing OS name and release codes. Tools like `dch` add `-MubuntuN` to the version number instead of `-MdebianN`. Perhaps you should ask more specific questions about your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/):

> Welcome to the Ubuntu Packaging and Development Guide! This is the
>   official place for learning all about Ubuntu Development and
>   packaging.

Section [6. Packaging New Software](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) provides the details on building a package; Section [7. Security and Stable Release Updates](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/security-and-stable-release-updates.html) dives into security issues; Section [11. Backporting software updates](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/backports.html) takes care of back-ports. There is much more, it won't hurt if you read it all before starting.

The Wiki entry on [HelpingUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HelpingUbuntu#Maintain_Ubuntu) advises the procurement of a [MOTU mentor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DeveloperAdvisoryTeam?action=show&redirect=MOTU%2FMentoring).

Answer (score 0):

Ok，you should read it firstly.https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/.   then you should try to create a simple debian package. you know ，dpkg is the main tool for creating package . so you can find information by using man command.

Comment: I have. several. but then I get into more complex packages, and I'm not sure where the problem is... and I get warnings about package quality. and other packages get hung up in weird places. So I wonder, (i mean I know I'm a newb at this) but what if there is Ubuntu specific documentation we could read? What if there was another document, and it spoke to me, and I saw through my own idiocy, and managed to fix the problems I was previously having, using new insight? That would be fantastic!

Comment: Indeed, for ubuntu , there is a document for you  [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/). you can read it. if you met some problem, you should show us some errors log. Maybe , we can help you.